# what is change window?what does that mean when someone says july change window

Tags: meaning, american-english

what is change window?what does that mean when someone says july change window

I have been coming across this term quite frequently

Comment: What context is this phrases used?

Comment: Perhaps some sentence like "If we don't finish our requirements analysis by April, we won't finish the coding in time to implement the new software in the July change window."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change window is a term used in the IT world that denotes a scheduled time that a service provider or vendor is allowed to be "down" so they can institute upgrades, changes, and testing.  The client can expect to be down during a change window.

These are usually done during hours that have little to no impact on operations.  So a regular business may ask the vendor to have a change window on the weekend.  Normal internet maintenance is usually down in the wee hours of Saturday morning.

So a July change window would be the only downtime for that month that the client could expect and the vendor could make changes.  This would probably be noted in your contract or you Service Level Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to

**Change window**

(Service Transition) A regular, agreed time when **Changes or Releases** may be implemented with minimal impact on Services. Change Windows are usually documented in SLAs.

[change window](http://www.best-management-practice.com/gempdf/itil_glossary_v3_1_24.pdf)